# Testing Sql Connection Validity

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to write a method that will check if a database connection is valid or not. Here is the code behind my Test Connection button.

```
    private void TestConn_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DbConnection DBConnTest;

        if (DataSrc_cbx.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            DBConnTest = new SqlConnection("Server="+DatabaseAddress_Value+"; Database="+DatabaseName_Value+";Trusted_Connection=true");
            try
            {
                DBConnTest.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("\nTEST SUCCESSFUL\n");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TEST FAILED Exception Thrown: " + exception.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                DBConnTest.Close();
            }
        }
      }
```

The problem is that there is no exception thrown when I enter an invalid Database address ( or leave it empty all together), same applies to the Database name. It only throws an exception when there is no connection string, or in an incorrect format. So my question is, How do I make it check if there is indeed a server and a database on that server with the names input?

Comment: When I tried that same block of code on another PC (Win7 64bit, VS2012Ultimate), it worked properly as expected. Wherever a parameter is not correct an exception is thrown. Don't know if it is a system issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply validations on your Web Page if the fields are empty then prompt user to enter something. Now use this statement to check whether this database exist or not??

```
select name from sys.sysdatabases 
where dbid=db_id()
```

for user you need to ..
    SELECT id FROM user WHERE login="JohnSmith"
and see if it gives you any rows. If yes - user exists.

You can use this work-around.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me. The issue here is that you have to wait till the SQL timeout period elapses before the exception is thrown. This will not be a method that returns an immediate answer. If you wrap this try/catch with a WaitCursor, you will at least see when the code is running.

```
private void TestConn_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    DbConnection DBConnTest;

    if (DataSrc_cbx.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        DBConnTest = new SqlConnection("Server="+DatabaseAddress_Value+"; Database="+DatabaseName_Value+";Trusted_Connection=true");
        try
        {
            DBConnTest.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("\nTEST SUCCESSFUL\n");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST FAILED Exception Thrown: " + exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            DBConnTest.Close();
        }
    }
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
  }
```

Comment: It still yields the same results!

Comment: @BlackyDucky It worked for me, but took 60 seconds to throw an exception. Just noticed you are webforms, I tried it in winforms

Comment: I am not, its a Desktop Application, and Where did your code go?!

Comment: @BlackyDucky I added it back, I had removed it because I thought you were using webforms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute a query to connect to the database.

For SQL Server, I usually use `IDbCommand.ExecuteScalar` to execute:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

For Oracle:

```
SELECT banner from v$version where banner like 'Oracle%'
```

> Would you provide the complete code, please?

It would be something like:

```
try
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = ...)
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT @@VERSION";
            var result = (string) command.ExecuteScalar();
            MessageBox.Show("\nTEST SUCCESSFUL\n" + result); 
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEST FAILED Exception Thrown: " + exception.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks incomplete!

Take this example from Microsoft.[conexão c# com sql server 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/cadc54c7-b5ec-4f44-8c07-07a1c143ff89/conexo-c-com-sql-server-2008?forum=vscsharppt)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                foreach (SqlError error in ex.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.Number);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

It will return the DB error code (run the following query for a list of error codes:

select * from sys.messages where language_id=1033 and severity between 11 and 16

Microsoft also provide some guidance here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number(v=vs.110).aspx